# how to continuously "move" lat/lon pairs in a database?

Tags: database, cron, geolocation, rdbms, launchd

I'm designing a project where I'll be storing (potentially hundreds of thousands of) lat/lon pairs in a database. The pairs are associated with other data. The catch is that in addition to users manipulating this data, I also want the locations to change over time. My initial instinct was to set up a cron job that will adjust every lat/lon by a certain amount every day, but I realize that such an operation would be insanely inefficient.

So, any ideas on how to efficiently adjust a bunch of lat/lon pairs over time? My best thought so far is associating a "last changed" timestamp with each pair and have a process running that fires every few seconds, grabs n (maybe order 100? 1000?) pairs with the oldest timestamps, adjusts those pairs and updates the times. This way I'm constantly moving small amounts of data, instead of moving an overwhelming amount once a day. I'm still not convinced this is the best way to go, though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you tested updating a few hundred thousand rows, how long did it take?

Comment: I haven't tested. Which is my fault. The database isn't even configured yet, just trying to figure out an approach before I decide on a schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the amount that is added to each pair somewhere else, and rather than using the values in the database directly, add this stored offset amount whenever you retrieve and subtract it whenever you insert.

Comment: Interesting approach. What if I wanted my locations to move in a pattern other than a straight line? Or a given lat/lon pair has moved several times, each with different lat/lon deltas?

Comment: As long as all of the pairs are to move by the same delta then this approach will work. If you want some pairs to move differently then you'll have to do something else. You can still use this approach if there are only a small number of sets of pairs by storing which set each pair is in and adding the appropriate delta.

Comment: I suppose if I had many different deltas I could store them in the rdbms as well and do the math in the servlet.

Comment: With this approach, how would one query by location, if the pairs in the database aren't necessarily where they "actually are" location-wise, and each pair had a different delta?

Comment: `... where (lat = WHAT_YOU_WANT - DELTA1 and delta = DELTA1) or (lat = WHAT_YOU_WANT - DELTA2 and delta = DELTA2)` etc. It's not tidy though, and it gets pretty bad if you have more than about 2 deltas.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm planning on doing some testing today on a few different ideas, I'll let you know what I end up deciding. Marking this as answered since it got me thinking and was a new insight into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is right, that probably is the best way of adjusting latitude longitude gradually. The update query shouldn't hammer the server too hard though, and your not moving- Just changing?

Comment: Sorry, the database isn't moving, the conceptual locations stored in it are.